# how are chips and ics build

Tags: integrated-circuit, manufacturing, chip-design

I want to know what is the process and how are chips and ics manufactured which are used on motherboards of computer systems is there some good tutorial available for same so that i can try building one at home

Comment: I closed this question since it would require long explanations of the process that would be better found with proper research.

Comment: See it may be a useless question for those of you who know electronics well, for people like me who are doing it all from scratch answers here can  be a great resource and can provide a good starting point for those who want to learn things by themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely it's not happening. To properly build a working chip you need a clean room. These are very expensive to build and maintain. You'll also need a bunch of expensive tools:

1. Induction Furnaces
2. "Wet Bench" for doing stuff with chemical etching
3. Photo lithography equipment
4. Deposition machines (CVD, PVD, sputtering, etc.)
5. Physical etching equipment (Reactive Ion etching, etc.)
6. Testing/verification equipment
7. Packaging equipment

...

The list could go on and on. The clean room at my local university (not that great, but decent for MEMS type work) cost several thousands of dollars a year just to keep running, not taking into account materials, tooling/disposable supplies, etc. Students/faculty could have access to the lab for ~$50/hr, I believe (can't remember the exact rate). For a class I was in we built a simple resistive MEMS heater, taking numerous shortcuts and it still took several days (spread out over the semester) to build a semi-functioning device.

There is also the safety of working in a clean room. We handled chemicals that would very easily and quickly kill you if something goes wrong. Some are tightly controlled and you're unlikely to even be able to get a hold of them for personal uses.

Comment: I am not an an electronics guy this thing of making chips/ics has always fascinated me so I want to know more of it...

Comment: There are various books available. One I have is Fundamentals of Microfabrication by Marc J. Madou. It does not contain enough information to be able to start your own fab, but does give a very good overview of several common micromachining processes.